# CakePHP database design: associations for job board

Tags: php, mysql, database, cakephp

Hy everyone.

I'm actually building a job board with CakePHP and a little help for designing the database will be appreciated!

I have a table **jobs** with differents foreigns keys: 
`id, recruiter_id,  title, sector_id, division_id, experience_id` etc.

The associated table (sectors, divisions and experiences) have the same configuration `id, name and job_count` and sometimes on or two other fields (like company_count for sectors).

So I would like to know if there is better way to design these tables. I thought for putting the three of them in one table named **lists** with the keys: `id, value and list_name`. With this configuration I have just one request to do to get all the list and not 3.

My question is what is the "good way" solution ? May be there's another one ?

Comment: Can you clarify what "sector", "division", and "experiences" actually represent (in non-technical terms)?  This can help understanding the situation, which in turn allows us to provide better advice :)

Comment: Just create unique tables for each entity. I am not sure how you think you will be performing one request vs three. The SQL would have to have 3 JOINs no matter if you use one table or 3 _(since you have 3 foreign keys)_.

Comment: @Dave: sector is for the industry (pharmaceutical, technology, etc.), division is the department (marketing, finance, etc.) and experience is the minimum experience required for the job (1 year, 1 to 3 years, etc.)

Comment: @AgRizzo: with one table I  will not need the foreign key but directly the name

Comment: Please show an example of your single table solution with sample data for both **lists** and **jobs**.

Comment: @AgRizzo: I think that we are talking about different thing. When I say it's only request it's for setting the view. The first solution, I will calll each tables separatly when with the second solution I just have to call one list that regroup all of them (because it's the same table)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a found a solution by using a system of taxonomy. I created a table **terms** which contain the list of all terms that can be associated (sector, division, type of contrat, etc.).

Table **terms** `id, name, type`

And I created a second table **term_relationships** which contain all the association including the name of the model that is associated.

Tabe **term_relationships** `id, ref, ref_id, term_id`

"ref" refers to the associated model (example: Job or Applicant in my case), the "ref_id" refers to the associated data (which job or which applicant) and term_id refers to which terms is associated. I think is the most evolutive and cleaner solution.

Thanks all for your help (especially Grafikart from where I get the idea) and hope that this topic can help someone else !

Answer (score 0):

Seems kind of repetitive to have them in separate tables, when really they're all the same thing - properties of a job, and would have VERY similar table structures.

I would think you could create a single table for "job_properties" or something.

Each property could have a unique slug (if you wanted) or just use it's id.

```
// job_properties table example
id
slug // (optional or could be called "key" if you prefer)
type // (optional - "sector", "division", "min_exp")
name // (for use on the names of things like "marketing" or "technology")
value // (int - for use on things like minimum experience)
```

Then each Job would hasMany JobProperty.  It would also allow any job to have more than one sector if that is ever needed.

This would allow you to pull based on if a job has a particular property or set of properties and seems overall cleaner and more consolidated while not making it too obfuscated.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I think too that the first solution it's too repetitive. The solution you provided looks like an improved version of the list solution. The only problem is that my applicant and my company also belongs to sector (the candidates can specify their wishes in terms of employment and companies can select a sector)

Comment: I fail to see why that's a problem  They could still belong to a JobProperty.  But I'll leave it up to you and your specific application to determine the exact needs.